# Facebook banner ad in unity align to the bottom

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk, unity-game-engine, facebook-audience-network

cannot align the facebook audience banner ad to the bottom of my screen. i tried to nested it in a canves align the object to the bottom but when ever call the show method it start count from the top of the screen.
i tried to make it static like this

```
adView.Show(135);
```

it works fine on my phone but when i tried on bigger screen it's appear on the middle.
i tried also to change the static value with `adView.Show(canves.rect.height - 50);`
but the result is samiler  `adView.Show(AdUtility.height());`
but it's appear out of the screen.i use unity 5.2.2f1 and facebook audience sdk 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I founded a error in code at "AudienceNetwork/Library/AdUtility.cs"

```
public override double height (){
   return this.convert (this.deviceWidth ());}
```

Change to:

```
public override double height (){
   return this.convert (this.deviceHeight ());}
```

And use:

```
adView.Show(AdUtility.height() - 50) // if: AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50
```